# OpenCVSharp ImRead() function can`t load Image in Unity on macOS

Tags: c#, opencv, unity-game-engine

I am trying to load my image from disk with `Cv2.ImRead()` function. I have debugged that matrix is empty. I have tried load that image with another c# function or unity texture2d function and it was successfull. So where can be problem? Why is that matrix empty? I know that file was not loaded sucessfully, but why when other functions can do that.

File definitely exists and its okay - Another, not openCVSharp, functions will load that image. For example Unity function `Texture2D.LoadImage`  (after I loaded that picture to bytes) or c# `Image.FromFile`.

Thank you very much for any ideas.

```cs
Mat img = Cv2.ImRead("object.png"); // also jpg is not working, also tried absolute path - same result
UnityEngine.Debug.Log(img.Empty()); // returns true
UnityEngine.Debug.Log(img.Width); // returns 0
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54697425/7111561

are you sure the path is correct like that?

Comment: Yes when I wrote `File.Exists("object.png");` response was true, also I tried load it like unity texture and it was completly OK. Also I tried relative path and absolute path, same result img is empty. I have read almost all this answers on stackoverflow, I know that almost every `Cv2.ImRead()` problem is in path, but then why other methods can load it successfully? I really have no any idea what to do with this.

Comment: well it is possible that `File.Exists` and especially the Unity load methods use a relative data path while CV2 might alway require an absolute path

Comment: Yes but I have tried use relative and absolute path to `Cv2.ImRead()` and also tried absolute and relative path to `File.Exists()`, but result was like `File.Exists()` throw me both true, but `Cv2.ImRead()'  throws both empty :/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Had success loading the image bytes into a Texture2D then using that data in that Texture2D to fill the Mat's bytes. You can do this manually or the asset store has a [package that does TextureToMat](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/opencv-plus-unity-85928).

```
    private static Mat matImageFile(string filePath)
    {
        Mat matResult = null;
        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            // load into Mat type. Hack: workaround for Cv2.ImRead() being broke.
            byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
            var tex = new Texture2D(2, 2);
            tex.LoadImage(fileData); // this will auto-resize the 2,2 texture dimensions.
            matResult = OpenCvSharp.Unity.TextureToMat(tex);
            Cv2.CvtColor(matResult, matResult, ColorConversionCodes.BGR2GRAY);
        }
        return matResult;
    }
```